# how to use onchange="function(this.value)

Tags: javascript, onchange

i want to change article language by a select field, so i gave the options different values, and now i can't find out how to write the function.
Before i had have different buttons and it was easy. But now i have to do it for seven languages and i don't have enough space for the buttons. Hope somebody can help me. Many Thanks in advance.

```
    <select id="langbtn" name="langbtn" onchange="language(this.value)">
                <option value="">language</option>
                <option value="de">deutsch</option>
                <option value="es">español</option>
                <option value="jp">日本人</option>
                <option value="pt">português</option>
                <option Value="ru">русский</option>
                <option value="cn">中国</option>
                <option value="en">english</option>
            </select>

    function language() {
        if($(this).attr("value") == "de"){
                $.get('article_de.html', function(data) {
                    $('#article_language').html(data);
                })
                $.get('newstext_de.html', function(data) {
                    $('#newstext_language').html(data);
                })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Jquery to achieve the same you can register change event of Select list then check values of selected item and based on it make a get request like

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#langbtn').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='')
        return;

    $.get('article_' + $(this).val() + '.html', function(data) {
        $('#article_language').html(data);
    });

    $.get('newstext_' + $(this).val() + '.html', function(data) {
        $('#newstext_language').html(data);
    });

});

});
```

please refer fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4uk23djf/1/

Comment: thanks a lot, this is quickly responded (to all) and understandable for an absolute beginner like me. YOU GUYS ROX!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value as a string and concatenate it into the URLs.

```
function language(lang) {
    if (!lang) return;
    $.get('article_' + lang + '.html', function(data) {
        $('#article_language').html(data);
    })
    $.get('newstext_' + lang + '.html', function(data) {
        $('#newstext_language').html(data);
    })
}
```

```js
function language(lang) {
    if (!lang) return;
    $('#article_language').text('You have selected: ' + lang);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="langbtn" name="langbtn" onchange="language(this.value)">
                <option value="">language</option>
                <option value="de">deutsch</option>
                <option value="es">español</option>
                <option value="jp">日本人</option>
                <option value="pt">português</option>
                <option Value="ru">русский</option>
                <option value="cn">中国</option>
                <option value="en">english</option>
            </select>
<div id="article_language"></div>
```

Comment: looks good, but get error   ...template/newstext_undefined.html

Comment: @jensmart Answer updated to use argument `lang` to get the value for the select. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen change with js code.

```
$('#langbtn').on("change",function(){
     if($(this).attr("value") == "de"){
                $.get('article_de.html', function(data) {
                    $('#article_language').html(data);
                })
                $.get('newstext_de.html', function(data) {
                    $('#newstext_language').html(data);
                })
        }
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egvrcn/bumvbg4t/)